Nested AD Security Groups are not granting access in SQL Server Reporting Services
We have an Active Directory Group called "Finance Department" which includes all staff in the Finance department. E.g. Finance department includes:
Joe Smith (CFO)
Amanda Maths (Accountant)

We have a folder in SQL Server Reporting Services called "Finance". We want to create a group to access this folder that includes everyone in the "Finance Department" group, as well as the General Manager and Managing Director.
I've created an AD group called "Finance Reports" with the following members and assigned it as Browser to the Fiannce reports folder:
Finance Department (group above)
John Smith (GM)
Joe Jones (MD)

John Smith and Joe Jones both get access to the finance folder, however users who are in the Finance Department group are not getting access.
Is there a limitation in SSRS to prevent nested security groups?
